How best to tightly wind air core inductors?
We all know air-wound solenoid inductors. We typically wind AWG 18 to 28 UEW solid copper wire on a drill bit, pen shaft, or any other cylindrical support and remove it. The support's diameter is typically 3mm to 50mm.
When the diameter is relatively small, a tight winding is relatively easy. However, the diameter must be larger to achieve a large Q. Winding a 30mm diameter air-wound solenoid with AWG 18 (1mm diameter; single or double spaced) in the same technique will be loose (the actual coil will have a diameter greater than 30mm). Well-wound tight inductors exist; I just don't know how to make them, which is the subject of this question.
For this question, I'm not considering using a bobbin, coil form, or toroidal core (#0 phenolic core). I've already used T130-0 but want to make a bigger Q. I'm also not looking to tie the coil with a plastic thread or support with a custom PCB and glue with Q Dope (polystyrene solvent cement typically used on inductors and transformers).

I suspect the answer lies in mechanical accuracy for the winding process. Probably, a lathe spinning a cylinder with a hole to affix the beginning of the coil to (possibly fixed in that hole with some sort diagonal screw), and an automatic tool feed that moves parallel to the axle, exactly one wire diameter per turn of the lathe, feeding in the wire through bobbins, together with a tensioner that keeps the wire at a constant tension while it is being fed. But that's my guess on how to make good coils – never done so.

@MarcusMüller Yes mechanical. Tension, temperature, special jig, etc. or some rules of thumb to compensate for the fattening of the coil so that the design calculation can factor in the fattening. Anything along those lines.

Also maybe using hard drawn copper intended for jewellery, or a hard copper alloy (berellium?), to make it mechanically strong. Regular copper wire is fully annealed to make it easier to handle and give it the best service life. Even just hand-stretching it (a lot, until it breaks somewhere) will make it much harder. and why only 18 Ga for a 30 mm coil? Use 16 or 14?

ARRL helpfully suggests methods to build big copper coils with supports: https://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9708033.pdf

@RyujiAB1WX for stiff wires, after-fact fattening shouldn't be an issue if you adjust your wire-bending bobbins such that the bend radius is correct for the cylinder you're working on. (the cylinder is the tool to keep the coil aligned and the linear movement defined, not necessarily to bend the wire into a concentric shape)

@MarcusMüller I'm winding by hand, but with as much stretch as I can give. I found a hard copper wire and 2.0mm solid copper harvested from Loomex scrap. They both fatten about the same as regular 18 AWG UEW, maybe a tiny bit less but still significant.

@RyujiAB1WX you will have to stop doing the bending by hand – get / build a rig with three rollers that touch the wire from 1. below 2. above 3. below, and adjust the vertical position of the 2. one until pushing wire through that contraption bends it at exactly the radius you need

Unsupported large coils tend to be wiggly, jiggly and microphonic. Especially noticeable when loaded Q is high.
In high-power applications, one might want a support structure of ceramic that retains its mechanical shape at high temperatures.
For lower-power applications, support material might shift to plastics that are more easily workable. Pure polystyrene having no additives is a good choice. But it can't take high temperature.
Commercial high-Q coils are still available, but convincing them to sell small quantities to individuals may be difficult:

If you wind your own onto a cylindrical form, one trick is to pre-wind the wire tightly onto a form with slightly smaller diameter. When released, it will spring to a larger diameter, hopefully still slightly smaller than the final form diameter. The pre-wound floppy coil is then carefully "threaded" onto the final form. Winding should end up snug against the form, if you work slowly and gently.
For coil support, I have drilled holes very slightly larger than wire diameter in a thin plastic sheet, with hole separation equal to winding pitch. The top row of holes is offset by one-half winding pitch compared to bottom row. A pre-wound "floppy" coil is then threaded through each hole - a tedious task:

